# Are C# LinqPad answers encouraged?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

The question [Find i^n, given n](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/41719/find-in-given-n) does not clearly state whether the solution must be a compilable program or can be an expression, neither does it identify where the input shall come from.

This leads to answers like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41803/16901), which are a mixture of both and neither short nor compilable.

For verbose languages like C#, are LinqPad C# expressions encouraged in [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)? If so, how to get the needed input?

A solution like

```
"i,-1,-i,1".Split(',')[n%4]
```

is nice and short and can compete with several other answers. But `n` would need to be replaced by the actual number, which increases the length. Is that allowed and by definition we count `n` just as 1 character?

**Edit**

There are [38 LinqPad answers already](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=LinqPad%20[code-golf]), applying the rules more or less lax. From the top-voted ones:

- [This one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32333/16901) might be ok, because it does not need input, but prints output to the LinqPad STDOUT if you like
- [That](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19587/16901) uses a string as input but does not count it as characters
- [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36230/16901) follows my example above
- [Another approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/33075/16901) seems to be a function that uses LinqPad specific methods (`.Dump()`)
- [This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45782/16901) takes advantage of missing `using`statements in LinqPad

Comment: Related: [Code Golf Input Output Methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: You've just answered your own question with that link. The other relevant poll [was this one](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2419/8478). We've got accepted defaults on these matters, which are also listed on the [tag:code-golf] tag wiki. Any answer may overrule these defaults, but if it doesn't then they apply. In particular, the current consensus is that snippets are *not* allowed.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: If it is a function, I guess it does not need the access modifier like in the linked i^n answer.

Comment: Does it not? Is it a mandatory part of a function definition in C#?

Comment: @MartinBüttner: By default it is private, but you can still call it from within your own program.

Comment: Yes, I'd say that's fine then.